# Target "qnx" does not exist in the project "Build and deploy a Cordova BB Webworks project"

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

So what I'm trying to do is build the Cordova sample project that came with the latest Phonegap version. I have followed the steps and downloaded the necessary tools for BB development as per the Phonegap website. When I go to the command prompt and attempt to build the project using the recommended command, I get this error...

> Build failed: Target "qnx" does not exist in the project "Build and deploy a Cordova Blackberry Webworks project"

I navigated to my project folder and typed

> "ant qnx build"

Any ideas where I am going wrong? Also just to mention that I'm using the "WebWorks" SDK for developementand the "Ripple" emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* that as of Cordova 2.8 this may have changed. We're in the process of doing some new documentation updates for BlackBerry 10 right now.

If you head on over to the Cordova 'Getting Started Guide' I think it'll get you moving in the right direction again.

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.8.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry10_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20BlackBerry%2010

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying that as of Cordova 2.8 that we will not be able to build BB10 apps using the Webworks SDK? Just for clarity, I'm following the "Getting started guide for BlackBerry" located here "http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20BlackBerry"

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm just saying that some of the command lines are different. You *can* absolutely still target BB10, I would just recommend following the getting started from the cordova website rather than the guide from the phonegap site (which will be updated) for now.

Comment: There is a separate getting started guide for the BLackBerry 10 OS (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry10_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20BlackBerry%2010)

Comment: @jeffheifetz Oops! i failed to mention that I'm using the "WebWorks" SDK for developement & the "Ripple" emulator.

Comment: Yeah Ripple doesn't have integration into building a phonegap project. But there is a whole slew of tooling coming around the new cordova CLI.